Pages and lines in a paper. What does the reviewer mean?
Recently the editor of the American Mathematical Monthly informed me that I should revise my paper according to suggestions of the reviewers.
The problem is that the second reviewer suggests something like

(2) p. 1, l. 12: it would be good to explain the notation Z_n.
(3) p. 1, l. -6: add the information that n and k are fixed.

The problem is that I cannot understand what he means.
(2) page 1, line 12?
(3) page 1, line -6?
This does not make sense, since Z_n does not appear in line 12 and what is line -6?

LIne $-6$ is $6$ lines from the bottom of the page.

About the other comment: I don't really see how anyone here can tell you what the reviewer means, but one thing you can do is look for the notation Z_n in lines around line 12: if your file does not have line numbers it may be that the reviewer counts headings, displayed equations etc. differently than you do.

You could ask the editor to send you the manuscript formatted the way the reviewers received it so that the line numbers are more likely to match (they still may not depending on how the reviewer viewed it), but it seems like if you know your manuscript well the line numbers are not needed. You need to look where Z_n is used and explain the notation. You need to look where n and k are used for fixed variables and explain there that they are fixed. These seem like very clear comments, not something vague without line numbers like "please rewrite the sentence on page 8 line 6".

Not an answer. I'm surprised that a reviewer would think a Monthly reader would need Z_n defined, unless it appears far from any number theory context. And congratulations on such a positive review. The Monthly is hard to publish in.

Often the journal submission software adds its own page and line numbering to the document - which does not always match the 'obvious' numbering. Log in to the submission system and look for the automatically-generated pdf.

As a statistical reviewer, I can affirm that what I get often has a variety of page and line numbers. I often see two sets and sometimes three!  I thought this problem was mostly from the journal I do most of my reviews for, sad to see that it seem to affect other journals too.

@EthanBolker The notation Z_n can mean different things in different contexts/countries: the cyclic group of order n, the set of n-adic integers, or even sometimes the localization of the ring Z at the element n. That's probably what the reviewer means; say explicit what notation you're using.

As a mathematician, I get referee reports like this a lot. As the comments have noted, "line -6" means six lines from the bottom of the page. Another point is to make sure you are looking at exactly the same PDF that the referee was looking at. This is why version control is so essential. If you are going to make any modifications after submitting the paper but before getting the referee report, it's essential to keep an untouched copy of the version that was submitted, to make sense of the referee report.
When I write referee reports, I try to avoid the line number approach to giving feedback, unless there are literally line numbers in the margins, because I think there's ambiguity as to how to count lines. This seems especially true when there are displayed math lines.
In your case, it's clear what to do. Find the very first place in the paper that the notation Z_n appears, and then add a sentence explaining that notation. Note that referees are humans too and can make mistakes. Maybe they wrote down the wrong line or page number. If it's clear what they meant, you can ignore the line number business. If it's not clear, then in the response to the referee document you could write "(2) We searched, but were unable to find what the referee was referring to. Can you please clarify?" Note that this will drag the process out, but sometimes it's necessary if you just can't figure out what the referee was talking about.
